How can I overlay an image in React like I can in raw DOM?
I have intermediate experience with JavaScript, and am now getting comfortable around Typescript. I'm currently writing a plugin for Vencord. I took existing javascript code and turned it into this Typescript code:
/*
 * Vencord, a Discord client mod
 * Copyright (c) 2024 Vendicated and contributors
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0-or-later
 */

import { Devs } from "@utils/constants";
import definePlugin from "@utils/types";


const imgs = [
    "fruit.jpg",
    "fruit2.png",
    "wellsfargo.png",
    "goosecreakfreak.jpeg",
    "joakim.gif",
    "xsb1.gif"
];
const gitRepo = "https://codeberg.org/api/v1/repos/zav/brainrot-gallery/raw/";
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
let img;

export default definePlugin({
    name: "brainrotGallery",
    description: "Randomly displays brainrot memes/random pictures",
    authors: [Devs.zav],

    start() {
        console.log("its time...");
        r();
    }

});

async function generate() {
    if (img && img.parentNode) {
        img.parentNode.removeChild(img);
    }
    img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = `${gitRepo}${imgs[Math.floor(Math.random() * imgs.length)]}`;
    img.style.width = "100%";
    img.style.height = "100%";

    document.getElementById("app-mount").appendChild(img);

    await delay(1500);
    fade();
}
function fade() {
    var intervalID = setInterval(function () {

        if (!img.style.opacity) {
            img.style.opacity = 1;
        }

        if (img.style.opacity > 0) {
            img.style.opacity -= 0.1;
        } else {
            clearInterval(intervalID);
            console.log("done");
            if (img && img.parentNode) {
                img.parentNode.removeChild(img);
            }

        }
    }, 200);
}

function r() {
    console.log("refreshing...");
    generate();
    setTimeout(r, 45 * 1000);
}


Every 45 minutes it overlays the Discord client with a random GIF or image. I'm unsure how to do this in React because it seems like the documentation/guides that I read don't show how to modify an already existing element.
However, I have to use React for it to be possibly accepted, and I have only a little experience with using React. Is it possible to overlay images over elements like I did with this raw DOM example?

"I have to use React for it to be possibly accepted" - what is accepted where? No, you cannot and should not do this with React.

"I have to use React for my pull request to be possibly accepted and for my plugin to be added."

You can do it using Portals. You can implement the img element stuff as a react component then portal that into #app-mount. It will append it to the end
